# How to pass char into function?

Tags: c, string

I want to randomise my string so this is my code.

```
while(strcmp(word,"END")!=0)
{
printf("Enter word");
fgets(input,sizeof(input),stdin);
sscanf(input,"VERTEX %s",key1);
strcpy(list[count],key1);
count++;
}
random(list);
```

I declare list and key1 as `char list[32],key1[32];`
Then I tried to pass it into this function

```
void random(char* list)
{
    int i = rand()%5;
    char key1[32];
    printf("%d",i);
    printf("%s",list[i]);
    strcpy(key1,list[i]);
}
```

but it gave me this warning

```
incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'char'
  to parameter of type 'char *'
```

And it can't print. Any suggestion?

Comment: The compiler tells you the problem: `incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'char'  to parameter of type 'char *'` next time try searching for that error

Comment: `char list[32];` -->  `char list[5][32];`and `void random(char* list)` --> `void random(char list[][32])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

void random(char list[][32], char *key, int size){
    int i = rand()%size;
    printf("choice %d\n",i);
    printf("choice key is %s\n", list[i]);
    strcpy(key, list[i]);
}

int main(void){
    char list[5][32], key1[32], word[32];
    int count = 0;
    srand(time(NULL));

    while(1){
        printf("Enter word : ");
        fgets(word, sizeof(word), stdin);
        if(strcmp(word, "END\n")==0)
            break;
        if(count < 5 && 1==sscanf(word, "VERTEX %s", key1)){
            strcpy(list[count++],key1);
        }
    }
    if(count){//guard for count == 0
        random(list, key1, count);
        printf("choice key : %s\n", key1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it have an error when you run this code. It has floating point exception @BLUEPIXY

Comment: @asiandudeCom it work fine to me. [DEMO](http://ideone.com/qskZbZ) Do you have any input? By the way, **I don't use the floating point.**

Comment: I have input about 3 words then floating point error come up @BLUEPIXY

Comment: Did you what input ? , is not a number of word. robably correct input is because there is no one. So `count` is `0`.

Comment: I input word like "look", "exit" and "word" and then i type END then error came up.

Comment: your input format is `"VERTEX %s"`.  need pre-input `VERTEX`. If there is no prefix string,  `"VERTEX %s"` change to `"%31s"`

Answer (score 0):

if you have defined `char list[32];`, callled `random(list);` and used `void random(char* list)`, then

```
   strcpy(list[count],key1);
   printf("%s",list[i]);
   strcpy(key1,list[i]);
```

all the statements are wrong.

- [`strcpy()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy) expects its paramaters to be `char *` and `const char *`, respectively.
- [`%s` format specifier](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) in `printf()` expects a `char *`, not a `char`.

In your code, `list[count]` and `list[i]` is of type `char`, not `const char *` or `char *`, as required.

Comment: I want to copy key1 into an array not copy list[i] into key1. @Sourav Ghosh

Comment: @asiandudeCom updated my answer to add some more clarification. Please check.

Comment: what do you mean by not initialized I already declared it @Sourav Ghosh

Comment: @asiandudeCom do you first understand that `list[count]` cannot hold a _string_?

Comment: what if i change into list[32][20] an 2D array. Can it hold? @Sourav Ghosh

Comment: @asiandudeCom Yes, what you need is `list` to be a 2D array.

Answer (score 0):

```
void random(char *list);
```

So here `list` is pointer of type `char` and when you pass a valid char array to this API then list points to your array `list`.

Now what you need is just

```
   printf("%s",list); /* Format specifier %s needs char * */
   strcpy(key1,list); /* The arguments should be char * */
```

Comment: Am I using strcpy wrong in the while loop? and i want to copy a key1 that have been sscanf into an array. @Gopi

Comment: @asiandudeCom If you want to store multiple strings then you should have a 2D char array or array of char pointers .. So Yes what you do in while loop is wrong. Chage list to `list[32][100];` and make sure you `char *` and not `char` to the API's